# Parse/Do a filter a javascript string with a lot of select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a var in js like this :

```
var string = 
"<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
<option value="1">D</option>
<option value="2">E</option>
<option value="3">F</option>
<option value="1">G</option>
<option value="2">H</option>
<option value="3">I</option>
<option value="1">K</option>
<option value="2">L</option>
<option value="3">M</option>"
```

And i would like to create a code which parse it/do a filter, in order to keep in a new var only option with val= value i choose.

So the result i would like to obtain for exemple for value=1 is following :

```
"<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="1">D</option>
<option value="1">G</option>
<option value="1">K</option>"
```

Do you have an idea how to do?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Prusse - ewww!!!  Much easier to use jQuery :)

Comment: Also, I do hope this isn't a copy and paste from an existing script - it's syntactically horrible!

Comment: @Archer I doubt it, it's not even legal JS (double quotes enclosing the string and within the string)

Comment: @Alnitak Watch for a question, "Why does this string not work?" :p

Comment: @Archer at which point I'll point the OP at my jsfiddle, where I've fixed it...

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the string to the jQuery and use `.filter()` method.

```
var filteredElements = $(string).filter('[value=1]');
```

In case that you want a string representation of the elements:

```
var filteredString = $('<select/>').html(string).find('option').filter(function() {
    return this.value !== '1';
}).remove().end().end().html();
```

Comment: better IMHO to filter based on a direct test of the `.value` property than using a selector

Comment: (AFAIK jQuery / Sizzle can't optimise a test on an arbitrary set of elements into a single call to `querySelectorAll`)

Comment: It return an object, do you know how to return a string?

Comment: @ArnauddeVslt Why do you want a string, specifically?  If all you're going to do is add those options to the page, then that jQuery object (also as per my answer and jsfiddle) is more efficient.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, in most cases using `.filter()`'s callback function is more efficient than using 'string' selectors, unfortunately some of the programmers think that when something is shorter is it faster / more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You would be better keeping that as a set of jQuery elements:

```
var $options = $(string);
```

and then using jQuery methods to get the ones you want:

```
var $wanted = $options.filter(function() {
    return this.value == 1;
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/7ThYU/

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var string = 
"<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
<option value="1">D</option>
<option value="2">E</option>
<option value="3">F</option>
<option value="1">G</option>
<option value="2">H</option>
<option value="3">I</option>
<option value="1">K</option>
<option value="2">L</option>
<option value="3">M</option>"


var elements = $(string);
var requiredelements = elements.filter("option[value=1]").html();
```

Comment: why convert it back into serialised HTML?

Comment: true, the question suggests that, but I rather expect the OP is just going to insert that string back into the DOM anyway...

Comment: I think you mean `.html()` instead of `.innerHTML()`. Such a method does not exist.